# ipython notebook on remote server peculiarity

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am taking my first steps with ipython notebook and I installed it successfully on a remote server of mine (over SSH) and I started it using the following command:

```
ipython notebook --ip='*' ---pylab=inline --port=7777
```

I then checked on http://myserver.sth:7777/ and the notebook was running just fine. I then wanted to close the SSH connection with the server and keep ipython running in the background. When I did this, I couldn't connect to myserver.sth:7777 anymore. Once I connected again to the remote server by SSH, I could connect again to the notebook. I then tried to use `screen` to start ipython: I created a new screen by `screen -S ipy`, I started ipython notebook as above and I used `Ctrl+A,D` to detach the screen and exit to the TTY. I could still connect remotely to the notebook. I then closed the SSH connection and I got a `404 NOT FOUND` error when I tried to access my previously stored notebook and I couldn't see it on the list of notebook at http://myserver.sth:7777/. I tried to create a new notebook, but I got a `500 Internal Server Error`.

I also tried running `ipython notebook` with and without using `sudo`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using `screen -S ipy` is a good solution, but `screen -dmS ipy ipython notebook ...` is even better because you don't have to manually enter the command and detach.  You shouldn't use `sudo`, because then anyone who attaches to your notebook server has root on your machine.  But other than that, this question just doesn't have enough detail to be answerable; the description is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use screen, perhaps you could switch to an init script or [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to keep IPython notebook up and running.

Let's assume you go the supervisord route:

**Install supervisord**

Install supervisord using your package manager. For ubuntu it's named `supervisor`.

```
apt-get install supervisor
```

If you decide to install supervisor through pip, you'll have to set up its init.d script yourself.

**Write a supervisor configuration file for IPython**

The [configuration file](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) tells supervisor what to run and how.

After you install supervisor, it should have created `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`. These lines should exist in the file:

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

If they contain these lines, you're in good shape. I only show them to demonstrate where it expects new configuration files. Your configuration file can go there, named something like `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/ipynb.conf`.

Here's a sample configuration that was generated by Chef by an [ipython-notebook-cookbook](https://github.com/rgbkrk/ipython-notebook-cookbook) that runs the notebook in a virtualenv:

```
[program:ipynb]
command=/home/ipynb/.ipyvirt/bin/ipython notebook --profile=cooked
process_name=%(program_name)s
numprocs=1
numprocs_start=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=1
startretries=3
exitcodes=0,2
stopsignal=QUIT
stopwaitsecs=10
user=ipynb
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_capture_maxbytes=0
stdout_events_enabled=false
stderr_logfile=AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
stderr_capture_maxbytes=0
stderr_events_enabled=false
environment=HOME="/home/ipynb",SHELL="/bin/bash",USER="ipynb",PATH="/home/ipynb/.ipyvirt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games",VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/ipynb/.ipyvirt"
directory=/home/ipynb
serverurl=AUTO
```

The above supervisor config also relies on an IPython notebook configuration (located at `/home/ipynb/.ipython/profile_cooked/ipython_notebook_config.py`). This makes configuration much easier (as you can also set up your password hash and many other configurables).:

```
c = get_config()

# Kernel config

# Make matplotlib plots inline
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'

# The IP address the notebook server will listen on.
# If set to '*', will listen on all interfaces.
# c.NotebookApp.ip= '127.0.0.1'
c.NotebookApp.ip='*'

# Port to host on (e.g. 8888, the default)
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888 # If you want it on 80, I recommend iptables rules

# Open browser (probably want False)
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```

**Re-read and update, now that you have the configuration file**

```
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
```

## Reality

In reality, I used to use a [Chef cookbook](https://github.com/rgbkrk/ipython-notebook-cookbook) to do the entire installation and configuration. However, using configuration management with tiny stuff like this is a bit of overkill (unless you're orchestrating these in automation).

Nowadays I use Docker images for IPython notebook, orchestrating via JupyterHub or tmpnb.